# On what stack should I ask about FL Studio usage and particular problems in that program?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a house producer and sometimes I have a few problems with my DAW (FL studio).

As I really like the Stack Exchange model, I would like to know where I can ask questions about FL studio.

Where can I ask FL studio questions and get a good response?

Questions I want to ask:

1. Why does the patcher take up so much CPU power?
2. How to use spire on low quality?
3. what do I have to consider when using an EQ?
4. how to easily open the FL studio's file browser in Windows Explorer without going through all those folders?

Comment: Can you give an example question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [FL Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FL_Studio) is a digital audio workstation then [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be the right place:

> Questions that are on topic include questions about:
>
> - sound design in the film and video game industries
> - live production audio
> - mixing and recording in a studio from the perspective of the sound tech
> - field recording
>
> As long as your question is about one of these topics and is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other person interested in sound design
>
> ... it is welcome here.

If you're only asking about installation and/or use of the software in relation to its operating system [Super User](http://superuser.com) might be a better place.

Whatever site you choose visit their Help Center first and when in doubt if your question is on-topic ask on their meta first.